# Audio Mastering Book Recommendations

Tags: audio-recording, mastering

I am in the initial stages of a recording project of my own and am interested in doing my own mastering work once it is finished.  So, I am looking for books/reference materials on audio mastering as this will be as much about the learning experience as it is the finished product.

I have past experience in audio engineering, both live and in the studio, but have never approached the task of mastering.  What books, references, sites, etc...would any of you mastering folks recommend?

Comment: I converted this to CW as there is no single correct answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bob Katz "mastering audio"
You cannot go wrong.

Also, I think it's one of the most valuable sound engineering books in the market.

Comment: Thanks, @jlebre--just ordered it...this will be the first in my library of audio mastering ;-)

Comment: it is scientific. Nice way to brush up on the maths through the initial "concepts" bit. I had the "pleasure" (i guess, not sure pleasure it's still the right word) of meeting the guy last year.

Comment: +1 on Mastering Audio. Bob's standards are incredibly high.

Comment: Katz's book is great, although I think it is a poor choice to master your own project. There is something to be said about having a pair of fresh ears listen to your project after you have ingrained every note in your head through the mixing process. Another engineer can spot something you have become too familiar with to catch.